# One single command to update everything in Ubuntu?

Tags: command-line, upgrade, updates

I know that there are three command to update and then upgrade the whole system, these are:

- `sudo apt update`: Fetches the list of available updates
- `sudo apt upgrade`: Strictly upgrades the current packages
- `sudo apt full-upgrade`: Installs updates ([add or remove packages](https://askubuntu.com/a/1398989/349837)), [equivalent of dist-upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/a/770140/349837)

Is there a super-upgrade command that **combines** all these commands to one?

Comment: No, you can do at most `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: It's still one command-line!  **;-)**

Comment: For those who shall stumble upon this question someday, here's a related one to run `update` and `upgrade` as one-liners https://askubuntu.com/a/1086022/295286

Comment: I have a folder that contains all of the custom commands I run /NSCS/bin

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There are 3 decent choices:

1. You could create a script something like the following:

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash
   set -e
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```

   Call it something like `update.sh` and place it in `/usr/local/bin` and then make the script executable by running:

   ```bsh
   sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/update.sh
   ```
2. Another method would be to create a bash alias (in `~/.bashrc`) or wherever you normally store your aliases:

   ```bsh
   alias update='sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade'
   ```
3. A final method would be to simply string the 3 commands together on the commandline:

   ```bsh
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```

A few choices...

**Reference:**

- [Combine apt-get update and apt-get upgrade in one command](https://scottlinux.com/2012/08/01/combine-apt-get-update-and-apt-get-upgrade-in-one-command/)

Comment: When you are using `dist-upgrade` there is no point in doing `upgrade` beforehand..

Comment: @heemayl: In theory yes. In practice there are corner cases where a direct `dist-upgrade` may fail but `upgrade` followed by `dist-upgrade` will not. This is largely due package dependency definition bugs or mixing packages from different releases/distributions/PPAs. If one only uses packages from Canonical's official repositories for exactly one release (the default), such errors should be extremely rare and fixed quickly.

Comment: There's also the *impress-friends* variant of #3: `for x in update {,dist-}upgrade; do sudo apt $x; done`

Comment: In step 1, what does "set -e" do?

Comment: @karjedavpalaa - "-e  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status."

Answer (score 41):

We can have a one-liner command (no need to scripts, just copy-paste)

```
sudo apt update -y && sudo apt full-upgrade -y && sudo apt autoremove -y && sudo apt clean -y && sudo apt autoclean -y
```

- `update` - updates the list of packages but do not install
- `upgrade` - install new versions of packages if new versions are available
- `full-upgrade` - performs the function of upgrade but will remove currently installed packages if this is needed to upgrade the system as a whole (fixing bad dependencies then)
- `autoremove`, `autoclean` and `clean` - clean old packages which are not needed any more
- option `-y` does not request for permission on every step
- `&&` states that it just runs the next command if the previous was successfully executed

### Alias

You can also create an alias. Add the following line to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases` (if you have it)

```
alias upev='sudo apt update -y && sudo apt full-upgrade -y && sudo apt autoremove -y && sudo apt clean -y && sudo apt autoclean -y'
```

Run `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bash_aliases` accordingly to fetch your new alias, and now simply run

```
upev
```

note: I chose `upev` for UPgrade EVerything, but you may chose anything you want.

Comment: You can skip the `apt autoremove` if you add `--auto-remove` to `apt upgrade`

Comment: @CameronTacklind: For me, it is better to have autoremove in a different step to double-check if something would get removed which I use.

Comment: @emk2203 It will ask you to confirm the removals as well, unless you add `-y`.

Comment: Good to know, should have just tried it once before commenting. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

If you are annoyed by too much typing, you can define yourself an "alias". This can be done e.g. by adding a line to the end of your `$HOME/.profile` like this:

```
alias sau='sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude upgrade'
```

(of course you can replace "sau" by something else -- for me that's an acronym to Sudo Apt-get Update). After saving the file, open a new shell (or "source" the .profile again running `. $HOME/.profile`. Now you can always simply type "sau" to do the complete job. Works great for me with multiple machines.

Comment: Hm. I guess I was just asking someone to tell me to alias it :P

Comment: Yeah, but that's the only way to do it with a "single command". And your question did not exclude this ;)

Comment: Tricky. Anyways, the only reason I asked was because I wanted to understand apt better, not because I'm too lazy to write `sudo aptitude update && sudo aptitude upgrade` The reason I asked was because you can do it with pacman (`sudo pacman -Syu --noconfirm`).

Comment: If you have to do that often and on multiple machines, you're glad you can at least have an alias. However: `apt-get update` has a parameter `-u`, according to the man page that shows available updates. Did not try whether it then asks to apply them (have no Ubuntu/Debian near me to check right now).

Answer (score 6):

```
sudo apt install unattended-upgrades
```

This is the best line yet.   All the other solutions, you have to type the one line over and over again every day.    This is truly the one-command solution.  See [official apt documentation from Ubuntu!](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/package-management#heading--automatic-updates)

By editing the `.conf` files of this package in `/etc` you can set the frequency of `update, install, clean, autoremove`...

Or simply and email including A notification that an update is available with the list of package names.

A nice little log file is generated with each change, and I imagine a little script could be written as a GUI extension to pop up in the desktop notifications too (off-topic).

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the two commands have to be executed separately.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a super-upgrade command that combines all these commands to one?

Well.. bad news is that no, there isn't. Good news though is that here I've put together one.

And to go on with the idea of simplification I've turned its creation into a "single" command line. So here it is:

```
echo "sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade && sudo apt -y dist-upgrade && sudo apt -y autoremove && sudo apt autoclean" > update && sudo mv update /usr/local/bin/update && sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/update
```

Now, whenever the need for updating arises you just type `update` in the terminal, input your password and voilà.

---

This might look like one of those incomprehensible things you only copy-paste from. But it doesn't really have to be ! 
See it's actually quite simple, so..

### What this is :

1. Every update command (and then further commands) were concatenated using `&&` (including `apt autoremove` to remove no longer used dependencies).
2. `-y` was added to every `apt` command that would otherwise prompt for a positive answer to perform its actions.
3. `echo` was placed in front of the command and the line was surrounded with `""` so its characters wouldn't escape.
4. `>` was used to redirect/write `echo`'s output (our line) to an "update" file.
5. The file is moved to `/usr/local/bin/` so it is executable from anywhere. Writing on this path requires superuser access which is why it's not possible to do it in the step before.
6. The file was turned into an executable using `chmod`.

Answer (score 2):

Just copy-paste the following `alias` command and execute it:

```
alias fup='sudo apt-get -y update;sudo apt-get -y full-upgrade;sudo apt-get -y autoremove; sudo apt-get -y autoclean'
```

Now, running `fup` will automatically do all the jobs defined in the `alias`.

If you need to use this frequently, do the following.

1. Create a file named `.bash_aliases` in your `$HOME` directory. You can do that form the terminal with the following command:

   ```
   touch ./.bash_aliases
   ```
2. In the `.bash_aliases` file paste the `alias` command mentioned above.
3. Now save the file and exit.
4. Edit your `.bashrc` file to export your `.bash_aliases` file. So run:

   ```
   gedit .bashrc
   ```

   and paste the following code at the end of file:

   ```bash
   if [ -f /home/abhyam/.bash_aliases ];then
   source /home/abhyam/.bash_aliases
   fi
   ```
5. Save the file and exit.
6. Run:

   ```
   source .bashrc
   ```
7. Now you can run the command `fup` to fully update and upgrade your system anytime.

The benefit of creating the `.bash_aliases` file is that you can also create custom aliases in that file for other actions and that it will automatically get sourced each time you open a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread looking for the same treasure. In case anyone is still interested, [I've been working on a git project](https://github.com/HastedHamster/BasherUpdate/blob/main/BasherUpdate.sh) which runs through the same commands.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/bash
    RED='\033[0;31m'
    GREEN='\033[0;32m'
    PURPLE='\033[0;35m'
    NC='\033[0m' # No Color

#Region --- Updates
    echo -e "${PURPLE}RUNNING: sudo apt update --fix-missing${NC}"

for i in {1..100}
do  
    sudo apt clean
    sudo apt update --fix-missing
    status=$?
if test $status -eq 0
then 
    echo -e "${GREEN}SUCCESS: sudo apt update --fix-missing${NC}\n"
    break
else 
    echo -e "${RED}FAILED: sudo apt update --fix-missing${NC}\n"
    sleep 1m
fi
done

#Region --- Upgrades
for i in {1..100}
do  
echo -e "${PURPLE}RUNNING: sudo apt upgrade -y${NC}"
    sudo apt full-upgrade -y
    status=$?
if test $status -eq 0
then
    echo -e "${GREEN}SUCCESS: sudo apt upgrade -y${NC}\n"
    break
else 
    echo -e "${RED}FAILED: sudo apt upgrade -y${NC}\n"
    sleep 1m
fi
done

#Region
for i in {1..100}
do  
echo -e "${PURPLE}RUNNING: sudo apt autoremove -y${NC}"
    sudo apt autoremove -y
    status=$?
if test $status -eq 0
then 
    echo -e "${GREEN}SUCCESS: sudo apt autoremove -y${NC}\n"
    break
else
    echo -e "${RED}FAILED: sudo apt autoremove -y${NC}\n"
    sleep 1m
fi
done

#Region --- Exiting BasherUpdate
    echo -e "${PURPLE}Exiting BasherUpdate...${NC}\n"
    exit 0
```

Note that I used a loop on the `apt update` command because I was getting `mirror sync in progress` errors and wanted it to keep trying. Hope this helps and let me know if you have suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Found this elsewhere:

```
    sudo -- sh -c "apt update && apt upgrade -y"
```

Can also alias this to use 'upgrade' in your ~/.bash_aliases with something like:

```
    alias upgrade="sudo -- sh -c 'apt update && apt upgrade -y'"
```

and do a 'source ~/.bash_aliases' to make it work