# Reuse the `apt up` part of the `apt update` and `apt upgrade` commands to execute both in sequence in just one line

Tags: command-line, apt, bash, upgrade, updates

How to reuse the `apt up` part of the `apt update` and `apt upgrade` commands to execute both commands in sequence in just one line without an alias.

Something like: `apt up{date,grade}`.

Comment: What would actually be the aim of achieving this? Why may this be  interesting/relevant?

Comment: @vanadium we are linux users, trying pointless things allows us to learn techniques that can be applied later to more complex things, if none of us ever did that let's be honest none of us would be here

Comment: @DarrenH That is what I thought indeed :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The simple way ( and more efficient) is via for loop (on one line but here it's shown in multiple lines for clarity):

```
for i in {date,grade}; do
     apt up${i}
done
```

The smart way is to make an alias in `~/.bashrc` for these two commands and forget about retyping it ever again:

```
alias upgrade=' sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade'
```

The elaborate way is to do this:

```
$ echo sudo" "apt" "up{"date","grade"}" && " :
sudo apt update &&  sudo apt upgrade &&  :
```

See what's happening ? We're building a valid string of text to be run by shell. Now all you need to do is to use `eval` instead of `echo`. But `eval` is generally not recommended in shell scripting and this command is much more convoluted and non portable than the for loop. Variation on the theme without eval (and shortest so far, but not efficient due to pipe and multiple commands `echo`,two `apt`,`sudo` and `sh` so lots of forking):

```
$ echo "apt "{update,upgrade}";"|sudo sh
```

---

We can also use `set` to turn the desired sequence into positional parameters and just execute `apt` with `$1` and `$2` args:

```
$ set {update,upgrade}; echo apt $1 && echo apt $2
apt update
apt upgrade
```

Or alternatively use for loop again, since it defaults to processing positional parameters if you don't specify a sequence in the `for variable (sequence)`

```
$ set {update,upgrade} ; for i; do echo apt $i ;done
apt update
apt upgrade
```

Using `set` is a very common technique I see among professionals who work with shells a lot, and for a good reason - this is very portable and will work in `/bin/sh` where you have no arrays or `{a,b,c}` expansion. So POSIX-ly portable way would be `set update upgrade ; for i; do echo apt $i ;done`. Additionally, this should be efficient.

---

Or we can go the `while` loop route:

```
$ echo {date,$'\n',grade}|while read i;do echo apt up${i}; done 
apt update
apt upgrade
```

Of course remember to run it without `echo` for actual command execution to take place

Comment: Thanks. Alias is a good idea, but is there a way I can do it in the terminal with just one line without use an alias?

Comment: @e200  I'm pretty sure one could do it via elaborate and obscure bash tricks but there's no practical value to doing so.

Comment: Just do the for loop in one line. `for i in {date,grade}; do sudo apt up${i}; done`

Comment: You both right. But, it does not seems to be a good solution since its more easy to execute an `apt update && apt upgrade` rather then an `for i in {date,grade}; do sudo apt up${i}; done`

Comment: If you prefer to keep your files nice and tidy, you can put aliases in `~/.bash_aliases`, too. This file should be automatically sourced by `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: I've updated my answer with perhaps what you want. It is a one-liner, but I don't think if it makes  it any easier.  Frankly, there's no point in doing this when you want to run two commands (yes, that's two `apt` commands) with different arguments (update and upgrade), so I'll still say for loop is the way to go

Comment: No need for string expansion in for loop header, just name the iterations: `for i in date grade; do`

Comment: @rexkogitans In this case yes. That's just cattering to what was originally in question.  But hypothetically if we're doing something like `apt install libsomething libwhatever libblah` maybe `lib{something, whatever,blah}` would be more elegant. But yes, you're right, expansion isn't necessary here.

Comment: Such an alias should obviously be named `upgrate`.

Comment: @pipe Sorry I'm not very creative when it comes to naming things :)

Comment: Piping into `sh` is almost equivalent to using `eval` and has many of the same potential risks.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson Pretty much, yes.  That's why people advise not to run something like `wget http://sketchy-website.com/somescript | sh `.  In this case here it's safe enough, since we're generating `apt` command and doing that ourselves. Danger comes mostly when you submit command string generation to a user, so it's not under your control and they can generate something arbitrary.

Comment: Yes, I know the dangers. My comment was directed at your paragraph that proposes piping into `sh` as an alternative to `eval` and implies that it's safer.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I stated in that paragraph it's a "variation on theme" and nowhere implied it's safer. Alternative, yes. Safer, no. Feel free to edit that paragraph to make it clearer.

Answer (score 14):

You can also use bash [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Modifiers) to get parts of the current command line and modify it:

```
$ apt update; !#:s/date/grade
apt update; apt upgrade;
Reading package lists... Done
...
```

- `!#` is the current line
- `:s/date/grade` is a modifier that substitutes `date` with `grade`

Comment: You can even save 2 more characters by using `!#:s/dat/grad` instead

Answer (score 9):

Another simple option using `xargs` instead of `for`:

```
echo up{dat,grad}e | xargs -n1 apt
```

Test:

```
$ echo up{dat,grad}e | xargs -n1 echo apt
apt update
apt upgrade
```

However, I’d prefer a shell alias [just like Sergiy](https://askubuntu.com/a/1086022/250300) because these “simple” ways are not simple enough to be actually useful.

Comment: Very nice. Variation on the theme could be `printf "%s\n" {date,grade} | xargs -I% -n1 echo apt up%` although this is a bit longer

Comment: `printf '%s'` is generally good practice since you can't escape it, e.g. with `--help` or `-e`.

Comment: @YoYoYonnY Yes. Maybe `printf '%s\0'` would be even better, `xargs` has a flag to handle null terminated args

Answer (score 2):

Create a function like this:

```
repeat() { 
    for suffix in "${@:2}";
    do
        eval "$1""$suffix";
    done
}
```

Then you can run `repeat 'apt up' {date,grade}`.  This has the benefit of being reusable for totally different commands, although it's not saving you any typing for this one.

I'd certainly agree with some of the other answers that something like this is probably more useful:

```
alias apt-up='apt update && apt upgrade'
```

Answer (score 0):

@muru's answer led me to read up on [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Using-History-Interactively) and I found another variant

```
 $ sudo apt update
 $ ^dat^grad^
```

`^string1^string2^` is equivalent to `!!:s/string1/string2/`, which takes the last command and replaces `string1` with `string2`.

Answer (score -2):

I resuse the `apt-get up` part of the command using the following key sequence:

<kbd>Up Arrow</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd>