# Which single command can I have for Ubuntu maintenance?

Tags: upgrade, updates

I see we have `apt update` and `apt upgrade`, but then we should do `apt autoremove` and/or `apt autoclean`, etc.

Is there a single command for full Ubuntu maintenance?

Comment: Probable duplicates: https://askubuntu.com/questions/733434/one-single-command-to-update-everything-in-ubuntu, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086021/reuse-the-apt-up-part-of-the-apt-update-and-apt-upgrade-commands-to-execut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can have

```
sudo apt update -y && sudo apt full-upgrade -y && sudo apt autoremove -y && sudo apt clean -y && sudo apt autoclean -y
```

- `update` - updates the list of packages but do not install
- `upgrade` - install new versions of packages if new versions are available
- `full-upgrade` - performs the function of upgrade but will remove currently installed packages if this is needed to upgrade the system as a whole (fixing bad dependencies then)
- `autoremove`, `autoclean` and `clean` - clean old packages which are not needed any more
- option `-y` does not request for permission on every step