# I am trying to upgrade from ubuntu 18.10 to 19.04, and am unable to

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

I am trying to upgrade to Ubuntu 19.04 and am not able to. first, I tried this website: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DiscoDingo/ReleaseNotes to try and find out if there was simply something that I had missed. I tried the same commands on this page multiple times, but to no avail, as it kept giving me this error: Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
then I tried going to [One single command to update everything in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/733434/one-single-command-to-update-everything-in-ubuntu) to see if there was some kind of command I was missing out on. I tried again and it still did not work. then I went to this website: https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/troubleshooting-please-install-available-updates-release-upgrading/ because it seems that others had the same problem. This website did not help either as it gave me the exact same error again. I have run all of my updates many times over, on multiple different wifi networks, and if it helps, my computer is a Ubuntu computer that was originally running Windows 10, but I deleted it because it did not have all of the features I wanted from my operating system.  I now have new information and have found the problem, but I don't know how to solve it. my Simple direct media player package won't update, and I don't know why. I have now done some more testing and I found this:
The following packages have been kept back:
  libsdl2-2.0-0 libsdl2-dev
I'm not sure why this is happening and it would be nice if someone could get back to me.
I hope that this question can be answered so that I and many others with the same problem can get help. with best regards, consume555.

it is now 19 days later and I have found the solution on my own. As it turns out, my sdl library was not updating, so I simply deleted it. I have learned that I should always check the terminal before seeking help. Thank you to everyone who provided input and I apologize for any inconvenience caused on my behalf.

Comment: Had you fully upgraded your 18.10 box before you tried to `do-release-upgrade` as the message implies you hadn't (eg. you possibly had run `sudo apt upgrade` which upgrades within limits, but not a `sudo apt full-upgrade` without said limits). The first site you mentioned was an official Ubuntu wiki page, so it's what I'd trust, but we'll help if you provide the command you tried & exact error message you received.

Comment: I tried the official Ubuntu page and I just tried your command and neither of them worked. here is the output from the official site:

Comment: zamy@samy-HP-Pavilion-Notebook:~$ update-manager -c

(update-manager:9920): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:45:44.747: Theme file for DMZ-Black has no directories

(update-manager:9920): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:46:05.747: Theme file for DMZ-Black has no directories
debconf: DbDriver "passwords" warning: could not open /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat: Permission denied
debconf: DbDriver "passwords" warning: could not open /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat: Permission denied
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

Comment: and here is the message i got for your command

Comment: sudo apt full-upgrade
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  g++-7 gnome-themes-standard libarmadillo8 libglibmm-2.4-1v5 libiptcdata0
  libllvm3.9 libmircore-dev libopenmpi2 libqt5multimediaquick-p5
  libsamplerate0:i386 libsfml-system2.4 libtinfo5:i386 libxml++2.6-2v5
  libzita-alsa-pcmi0 libzita-resampler1 x11proto-gl-dev
  x11proto-xf86bigfont-dev
The following packages have been kept back:
  libsdl2-2.0-0 libsdl2-dev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libnuma1
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]

Comment: I had to remove some characters because of the character count, so let me know if there is some vital information I left out.

Comment: Please do not provide additional information in comments, edit your question, and put it there.  Questions/Answers allow a lot more formatting, editing, further if you don't get the formatting correct, we can help you to format questions (& answers) to make them easier to read.

Comment: sorry about that, will update information in the question now

Answer (score 2):

**1.Execute the below commands**

```
$ sudo apt update 
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

**2.Remove all no longer required packages**

```
$ sudo apt autoremove
```

**3.Begin the Ubuntu 19.04 upgrade process by executing the following command**

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade 
$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d  #To upgrade to Ubuntu 19.04 pre-release from 18.10
```

**4.Reboot your Ubuntu system**

Comment: Not sure if `//` works for comment in bash. Most people use `#` for comment

Comment: sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
this is the exact same error message I got when trying to update before

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix thz i edit my answer :D

Comment: I tried again today and it still didn't work.