# Ubuntu Upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 failed

Tags: upgrade, startup

today I tried to upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04 using

```
sudo apt-get -f upgrade
```

Now, Gnome isn't starting anymore. I tried "safe mode", but it feels like everything is giving me failure notices.

dpkg delivers:

```
An upgrade from "xenial" to "bionic" is not supported with this tool
```

failsafeX delivers a black screen.
"network" delivers:

```
grep: /etc/resolv.comf: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone know, what to do?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1137951/767495  check here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am trying to upgrade from ubuntu 18.10 to 19.04, and am unable to](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137923/i-am-trying-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-10-to-19-04-and-am-unable-to)

Comment: That command would not migrate you to 18.04 Ubuntu under any circumstances, so you merely broke your 16.04. The proper tool in Ubuntu is `do-release-upgrade`, which works well and is fully supported. Fix your 16.04 before attempting a release-upgrade - upgrading a broken system often makes the problems worse. Or simply backup your data and clean-install 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

- Restore a backup you made so you get back to 16.04.
- Use the 18.04 live session to install 18.04 without formatting. This should not touch your personal data. If anything does go wrong you could also ...
- Reinstall with formatting using a 18.04 installer. Then restore the backup you made of the personal data.

If there is no backup you could use a live session to extract your personal data from the disks and put them on an external disk. Do detach it safely before installing so there is no connection to it.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1143644/ubuntu-upgrade-from-16-04-to-18-04-failed  maybe its duplicate question can you clarify