# Issues while upgrading from 18.10 to 19.04

Tags: upgrade, 18.10, 19.04, do-release-upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade [Ubuntu 18.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.10_(Cosmic_Cuttlefish)) (Cosmic Cuttlefish) to [Ubuntu 19.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_19.04_(Disco_Dingo)) (Disco Dingo) and have tried the below steps:

```
nagadeep@MachineName:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for nagadeep:
Hit:1 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease
Ign:2 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 InRelease
Hit:3 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 Release
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease [97.5 kB]
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/longsleep/golang-backports/ubuntu disco InRelease
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease [97.5 kB]
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/longsleep/golang-backports/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Ign:10 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable InRelease
Hit:11 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release
Hit:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease
Hit:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Hit:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates InRelease
Hit:14 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Fetched 195 kB in 2s (78.6 kB/s) Reading package lists...
Done
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/longsleep-ubuntu-golang-backports-cosmic.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/longsleep-ubuntu-golang-backports-cosmic.list:3
W: Target Sources (main/source/Sources) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/longsleep-ubuntu-golang-backports-cosmic.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/longsleep-ubuntu-golang-backports-cosmic.list:3 nagadeep@MachineName:~$
```

Running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` returns the below:

```
nagadeep@MachineName:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  accountsservice acl acpi-support acpid adduser adwaita-icon-theme aisleriot alsa-utils amd64-microcode anacron app-install-data-partner
  apparmor apport apport-gtk apport-symptoms appstream apt apt-config-icons apt-utils aptdaemon aptdaemon-data aptitude aptitude-common apturl
  apturl-common aspell at-spi2-core avahi-autoipd avahi-daemon avahi-utils baobab base-files base-passwd bash bc bind9-host binfmt-support
  binutils binutils-common binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu bleachbit bluez bluez-cups bluez-obexd bolt brltty bsdutils bubblewrap build-essential
  busybox-initramfs busybox-static bzip2 ca-certificates ca-certificates-java cabextract cheese cheese-common chrome-gnome-shell
  chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra colord colord-data console-setup console-setup-linux coreutils cpp cpp-8 cracklib-runtime cups cups-browsed
  cups-bsd cups-client cups-common cups-core-drivers cups-daemon cups-filters cups-filters-core-drivers cups-ipp-utils cups-ppdc
  cups-server-common dash dbus dbus-user-session dbus-x11 dc dconf-cli dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service debconf debconf-i18n debianutils
  default-jdk default-jdk-headless default-jre default-jre-headless deja-dup desktop-file-utils dictionaries-common diffstat diffutils dirmngr
  distro-info-data dmidecode dmsetup dns-root-data dnsmasq-base dnsutils dpkg dpkg-dev e2fsprogs ed enchant eog espeak-ng-data evince
  evince-common evolution-data-server evolution-data-server-common fakeroot fdisk file file-roller findutils firefox firefox-locale-en
  firefox-locale-kn fontconfig fontconfig-config fonts-freefont-ttf fonts-gujr fonts-gujr-extra fonts-indic fonts-liberation fonts-liberation2
  fonts-lohit-deva fonts-lohit-gujr fonts-lohit-knda fonts-noto-cjk fonts-noto-mono fonts-opensymbol fonts-smc-anjalioldlipi
  fonts-smc-chilanka fonts-smc-dyuthi fonts-smc-karumbi fonts-smc-keraleeyam fonts-smc-manjari fonts-smc-meera fonts-smc-rachana
  fonts-smc-raghumalayalamsans fonts-smc-suruma fonts-smc-uroob fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-tlwg-garuda fonts-tlwg-garuda-ttf fonts-tlwg-kinnari
  fonts-tlwg-kinnari-ttf fonts-tlwg-laksaman fonts-tlwg-laksaman-ttf fonts-tlwg-loma fonts-tlwg-loma-ttf fonts-tlwg-mono fonts-tlwg-mono-ttf
  fonts-tlwg-norasi fonts-tlwg-norasi-ttf fonts-tlwg-purisa fonts-tlwg-purisa-ttf fonts-tlwg-sawasdee fonts-tlwg-sawasdee-ttf
  fonts-tlwg-typewriter fonts-tlwg-typewriter-ttf fonts-tlwg-typist fonts-tlwg-typist-ttf fonts-tlwg-typo fonts-tlwg-typo-ttf
  fonts-tlwg-umpush fonts-tlwg-umpush-ttf fonts-tlwg-waree fonts-tlwg-waree-ttf fonts-ubuntu fonts-wine foomatic-db-compressed-ppds
  friendly-recovery ftp fuse fwupd fwupd-signed g++ g++-8 gcc gcc-8 gcc-8-base gcc-8-base:i386 gconf-service gconf-service-backend gconf2
  gconf2-common gcr gdb gdbserver gdisk gdm3 geany geany-common gedit gedit-common geoclue-2.0 geoip-database gettext gettext-base ghostscript
  ghostscript-x gimp gimp-data gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 gir1.2-atk-1.0 gir1.2-atspi-2.0 gir1.2-dee-1.0 gir1.2-freedesktop gir1.2-gck-1
  gir1.2-gcr-3 gir1.2-gdesktopenums-3.0 gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0 gir1.2-gdm-1.0 gir1.2-geoclue-2.0 gir1.2-geocodeglib-1.0 gir1.2-glib-2.0
  gir1.2-gmenu-3.0 gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-goa-1.0 gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0
  gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-gtksource-3.0 gir1.2-gweather-3.0 gir1.2-ibus-1.0 gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-4.0 gir1.2-json-1.0 gir1.2-nm-1.0
  gir1.2-nma-1.0 gir1.2-notify-0.7 gir1.2-packagekitglib-1.0 gir1.2-pango-1.0 gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-polkit-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-rsvg-2.0
  gir1.2-secret-1 gir1.2-snapd-1 gir1.2-soup-2.4 gir1.2-totem-1.0 gir1.2-totemplparser-1.0 gir1.2-udisks-2.0 gir1.2-unity-5.0
  gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0 gir1.2-vte-2.91 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gir1.2-wnck-3.0 git git-man gjs gkbd-capplet glib-networking glib-networking-common
  glib-networking-services gnome-bluetooth gnome-calendar gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data gnome-control-center-faces
  gnome-desktop3-data gnome-disk-utility gnome-font-viewer gnome-getting-started-docs gnome-getting-started-docs-kn gnome-initial-setup
  gnome-keyring gnome-keyring-pkcs11 gnome-mahjongg gnome-menus gnome-mines gnome-online-accounts gnome-panel gnome-panel-data
  gnome-power-manager gnome-screenshot gnome-session-bin gnome-session-common gnome-settings-daemon gnome-shell gnome-shell-common
  gnome-shell-extension-appindicator gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock gnome-software gnome-software-common gnome-software-plugin-snap
  gnome-startup-applications gnome-sudoku gnome-terminal gnome-terminal-data gnome-todo gnome-todo-common gnome-tweaks gnome-user-docs
  gnome-user-docs-kn gnome-weather gnupg gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm gpgv grep
  grilo-plugins-0.3-base groff-base grub-common grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common
  gsettings-desktop-schemas gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-libav
  gstreamer1.0-packagekit gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps gstreamer1.0-plugins-good
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-vaapi gstreamer1.0-x gtk-update-icon-cache guile-2.2-libs
  gvfs gvfs-backends gvfs-bin gvfs-common gvfs-daemons gvfs-fuse gvfs-libs gzip hdparm hostname hplip hplip-data hunspell-en-gb hunspell-en-za
  hyphen-en-gb hyphen-en-us i965-va-driver ibus ibus-gtk ibus-gtk3 ibus-table im-config imagemagick imagemagick-6-common imagemagick-6.q16
  info init init-system-helpers initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin initramfs-tools-core inputattach install-info intel-microcode
  intltool-debian iproute2 iptables iputils-ping iputils-tracepath irqbalance isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common iso-codes iw java-common junit4
  kbd keyboard-configuration klibc-utils kmod krb5-locales language-pack-en language-pack-en-base language-pack-gnome-en
  language-pack-gnome-en-base language-pack-gnome-kn language-pack-gnome-kn-base language-pack-kn language-pack-kn-base
  language-selector-common language-selector-gnome libaa1 libaacs0 libaccountsservice0 libacl1 libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl libamd2 libaom0
  libapparmor1 libappindicator1 libappindicator3-1 libappstream-glib8 libappstream4 libapt-inst2.0 libapt-pkg-perl libapt-pkg5.0
  libarchive-zip-perl libarchive13 libargon2-1 libasan5 libasn1-8-heimdal libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libasound2 libasound2:i386 libasound2-data
  libasound2-plugins libasound2-plugins:i386 libaspell15 libassuan0 libatk-adaptor libatk-adaptor:i386 libatk-bridge2.0-0
  libatk-bridge2.0-0:i386 libatk1.0-0 libatk1.0-0:i386 libatk1.0-data libatomic1 libatspi2.0-0 libatspi2.0-0:i386 libattr1 libaudit-common
  libaudit1 libavahi-client3 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3 libavahi-common3:i386
  libavahi-core7 libavahi-glib1 libavahi-ui-gtk3-0 libavcodec58 libavfilter7 libavformat58 libavutil56 libbabeltrace1 libbabl-0.1-0
  libbinutils libblas3 libblkid1 libblkid1:i386 libblockdev-crypto2 libblockdev-fs2 libblockdev-loop2 libblockdev-part-err2 libblockdev-part2
  libblockdev-swap2 libblockdev-utils2 libblockdev2 libbluetooth3 libbluray2 libboost-date-time1.67.0 libboost-filesystem1.67.0
  libboost-iostreams1.67.0 libboost-locale1.67.0 libboost-system1.67.0 libboost-thread1.67.0 libbrlapi0.6 libbrotli1 libbsd0 libbsd0:i386
  libbz2-1.0 libbz2-1.0:i386 libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6:i386 libc6-dbg libc6-dev libcaca0 libcairo-gobject-perl libcairo-gobject2
  libcairo-perl libcairo2 libcairo2:i386 libcamd2 libcamel-1.2-62 libcap-ng0 libcap2 libcap2:i386 libcap2-bin libcc1-0 libccolamd2
  libcdr-0.1-1 libcheese-gtk25 libcheese8 libcholmod3 libchromaprint1 libclone-perl libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-1.0-common
  libclutter-gst-3.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcmis-0.5-5v5 libcodec2-0.8.1 libcogl-common libcogl-pango20 libcogl-path20 libcogl20 libcolamd2
  libcolord2 libcolorhug2 libcom-err2 libcom-err2:i386 libcommons-lang3-java libcrack2 libcroco3 libcryptsetup12 libcups2 libcups2:i386
  libcupsfilters1 libcupsimage2 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4 libdatrie1 libdatrie1:i386 libdazzle-1.0-0 libdb5.3 libdb5.3:i386 libdbus-1-3
  libdbus-1-3:i386 libdbus-glib-1-2 libdconf1 libdebconfclient0 libdee-1.0-4 libdevmapper1.02.1 libdjvulibre-text libdjvulibre21
  libdmapsharing-3.0-2 libdpkg-perl libdrm-amdgpu1 libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-common libdrm-intel1 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2
  libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2 libdrm2:i386 libdv4 libdvdread4 libdw1 libe-book-0.1-1 libebackend-1.2-10
  libebook-1.2-19 libebook-contacts-1.2-2 libecal-1.2-19 libedata-book-1.2-25 libedata-cal-1.2-29 libedataserverui-1.2-2 libedit2
  libedit2:i386 libefiboot1 libefivar1 libegl-mesa0 libegl1 libegl1-mesa libel-api-java libelf1 libelf1:i386 libenchant1c2a liberror-perl
  libespeak-ng1 libetonyek-0.1-1 libevdev2 libevdocument3-4 libevview3-3 libexif12 libexif12:i386 libexiv2-14 libexpat1 libexpat1:i386
  libexpat1-dev libext2fs2 libfakeroot libfcgi-perl libfdisk1 libffi6 libffi6:i386 libfile-fcntllock-perl libflite1 libfontconfig1
  libfontconfig1:i386 libfontembed1 libfprint0 libfreerdp-client2-2 libfreerdp2-2 libfreetype6 libfreetype6:i386 libfribidi0 libfribidi0:i386
  libfuse2 libfwupd2 libgail-3-0 libgbm1 libgcab-1.0-0 libgcc-8-dev libgcc1 libgcc1:i386 libgck-1-0 libgconf-2-4 libgcr-base-3-1 libgcr-ui-3-1
  libgcrypt20 libgcrypt20:i386 libgd3 libgd3:i386 libgdata-common libgdata22 libgdbm-compat4 libgdbm-compat4:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0
  libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-bin libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common libgdm1 libgee-0.8-2 libgegl-0.4-0 libgegl-common libgeoclue-2-0
  libgeocode-glib0 libgexiv2-2 libgfortran5 libgimp2.0 libgirepository-1.0-1 libgjs0g libgl1 libgl1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
  libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libglapi-mesa:i386 libgles2 libglib-object-introspection-perl libglib-perl libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-0:i386
  libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-data libglvnd0 libglvnd0:i386 libglx-mesa0 libglx-mesa0:i386 libglx0 libglx0:i386 libgmime-3.0-0 libgmp10
  libgmp10:i386 libgnome-autoar-0-0 libgnome-bluetooth13 libgnome-desktop-3-17 libgnome-games-support-1-3 libgnome-games-support-common
  libgnome-menu-3-0 libgnome-todo libgnomekbd-common libgnomekbd8 libgnutls30 libgnutls30:i386 libgoa-1.0-0b libgoa-1.0-common
  libgoa-backend-1.0-1 libgom-1.0-0 libgomp1 libgpg-error0 libgpg-error0:i386 libgpgme11 libgpgmepp6 libgphoto2-6 libgphoto2-6:i386
  libgphoto2-l10n libgphoto2-port12 libgphoto2-port12:i386 libgraphene-1.0-0 libgraphite2-3 libgraphite2-3:i386 libgrilo-0.3-0 libgs9
  libgs9-common libgsm1 libgsm1:i386 libgspell-1-1 libgspell-1-common libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgssapi3-heimdal
  libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0
  libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-0 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin
  libgtk-3-common libgtksourceview-3.0-1 libgtksourceview-3.0-common libgtop-2.0-11 libgtop2-common libgusb2 libgutenprint-common
  libgutenprint9 libgweather-3-15 libgweather-common libgxps2 libharfbuzz-icu0 libharfbuzz0b libharfbuzz0b:i386 libhawtjni-runtime-java
  libhcrypto4-heimdal libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386 libheif1 libheimbase1-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal
  libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhogweed4 libhogweed4:i386 libhpmud0 libhtml-parser-perl libhtml-tree-perl libhttp-daemon-perl
  libhx509-5-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal:i386 libhyphen0 libibus-1.0-5 libical3 libidn11 libiec61883-0 libimobiledevice6 libinput-bin
  libinput10 libio-pty-perl libio-stringy-perl libip4tc0 libip6tc0 libiptc0 libitm1 libiw30 libjack-jackd2-0 libjack-jackd2-0:i386
  libjansi-java libjansi-native-java libjansson4 libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 libjbig2dec0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg-turbo8:i386 libjs-jquery
  libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore libjson-c3 libjson-glib-1.0-0 libjson-glib-1.0-common libjsp-api-java libjsr305-java libk5crypto3
  libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1 libkeyutils1:i386 libklibc libkmod2 libkpathsea6 libkrb5-26-heimdal libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libkrb5-3
  libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0 libkrb5support0:i386 liblapack3 libldap-2.4-2 libldap-2.4-2:i386 libldap-common libldb1 liblirc-client0
  liblist-moreutils-perl libllvm7 libllvm7:i386 liblocale-gettext-perl liblouis-data liblouisutdml-bin liblouisutdml-data liblouisutdml8
  liblsan0 libltdl7 libltdl7:i386 liblua5.3-0 liblz4-1 liblz4-1:i386 liblzma5 liblzma5:i386 libmagic-mgc libmagic1 libmagickcore-6.q16-6
  libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra libmagickwand-6.q16-6 libmaven-resolver-java libmaven3-core-java libmbim-glib4 libmbim-proxy libminiupnpc17
  libmm-glib0 libmount1 libmount1:i386 libmozjs-60-0 libmpfr6 libmpx2 libmspack0 libmspub-0.1-1 libmtp-common libmtp-runtime libmtp9
  libmypaint-1.3-0 libmypaint-common libmysofa0 libnatpmp1 libnautilus-extension1a libncurses6 libncurses6:i386 libncursesw6 libneon27-gnutls
  libnet-dbus-perl libnet-dns-perl libnet-dns-sec-perl libnet-libidn-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libnettle6 libnettle6:i386 libnewt0.52
  libnghttp2-14 libnm0 libnma0 libnorm1 libnotify-bin libnotify4 libnspr4 libnss-systemd libnss3 libnuma1 liboauth0 libodbc1 libodbc1:i386
  libodfgen-0.1-1 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopenal1:i386 libopencv-core3.2 libopencv-imgproc3.2 libopenexr23 libopenjp2-7 libopenmpt0
  libopus0 libopus0:i386 liborc-0.4-0 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libosmesa6 libosmesa6:i386 libp11-kit0 libp11-kit0:i386 libpackagekit-glib2-18
  libpam-cap libpam-gnome-keyring libpam-modules libpam-modules-bin libpam-runtime libpam-systemd libpam0g libpango-1.0-0 libpango-1.0-0:i386
  libpangocairo-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386 libpangoft2-1.0-0 libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386 libpangoxft-1.0-0 libpaper-utils libpaper1
  libparse-debianchangelog-perl libparted-fs-resize0 libparted2 libpcaudio0 libpcre3 libpcre3:i386 libpcsclite1 libpeas-1.0-0 libpeas-common
  libperlio-gzip-perl libpgm-5.2-0 libphonenumber7 libpipeline1 libpixman-1-0 libpixman-1-0:i386 libplexus-classworlds-java
  libplexus-sec-dispatcher-java libplexus-utils2-java libplist3 libplymouth4 libpng16-16 libpng16-16:i386 libpolkit-agent-1-0
  libpolkit-backend-1-0 libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libpoppler-glib8 libpopt0 libpostproc55 libprocps7 libproxy1-plugin-gsettings
  libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager libproxy1v5 libpsl5 libpthread-stubs0-dev libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpulse0:i386 libpulsedsp
  libpwquality-common libpwquality1 libpython-all-dev libpython-dev libpython-stdlib libpython2-dev libpython2-stdlib libpython2.7
  libpython2.7-dev libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libpython3-stdlib libqmi-glib5 libqmi-proxy libqpdf21 libquadmath0
  libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer libreoffice-base-core libreoffice-calc libreoffice-common libreoffice-core libreoffice-draw
  libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk3 libreoffice-help-en-gb libreoffice-help-en-us libreoffice-impress libreoffice-l10n-en-gb
  libreoffice-l10n-en-za libreoffice-l10n-kn libreoffice-math libreoffice-ogltrans libreoffice-pdfimport libreoffice-style-breeze
  libreoffice-style-colibre libreoffice-style-elementary libreoffice-style-tango libreoffice-writer librest-0.7-0 librhythmbox-core10
  libroken18-heimdal libroken18-heimdal:i386 librsvg2-2 librsvg2-common libsane-common libsane-hpaio libsane1 libsane1:i386 libsasl2-2
  libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules:i386 libsasl2-modules-db libsasl2-modules-db:i386 libsbc1 libsdl1.2debian libseccomp2
  libsecret-1-0 libsecret-common libselinux1 libselinux1:i386 libsemanage-common libsemanage1 libservlet-api-java libservlet3.1-java
  libsigc++-2.0-0v5 libsisu-inject-java libsm-dev libsm6 libsmartcols1 libsmbclient libsnapd-glib1 libsndfile1 libsndfile1:i386 libsndio7.0
  libsndio7.0:i386 libsnmp-base libsnmp30 libsnmp30:i386 libsodium23 libsonic0 libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup2.4-1 libspeechd2 libsqlite3-0
  libsqlite3-0:i386 libss2 libssh-4 libssh-gcrypt-4 libssl1.1 libssl1.1:i386 libstartup-notification0 libstdc++-8-dev libstdc++6
  libstdc++6:i386 libsub-name-perl libsuitesparseconfig5 libswresample3 libswscale5 libsynctex2 libsysmetrics1 libsystemd0 libsystemd0:i386
  libtag1v5 libtag1v5-vanilla libtalloc2 libtbb2 libtdb1 libtdb1:i386 libteamdctl0 libtevent0 libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl
  libthai-data libthai0 libthai0:i386 libtheora0 libtheora0:i386 libtiff5 libtiff5:i386 libtinfo6 libtinfo6:i386 libtotem-plparser-common
  libtotem-plparser18 libtotem0 libtracker-sparql-2.0-0 libtsan0 libu2f-udev libubsan1 libudev1 libudev1:i386 libudisks2-0 libumfpack5
  libunistring2 libunistring2:i386 libunity-protocol-private0 libunity-scopes-json-def-desktop libunity9 libunwind8 libupower-glib3
  liburi-perl libusbmuxd4 libuuid1 libuuid1:i386 libv4l-0 libv4l-0:i386 libv4lconvert0 libv4lconvert0:i386 libva-drm2 libva-wayland2
  libva-x11-2 libva2 libvisio-0.1-1 libvisual-0.4-0 libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libvncclient1 libvolume-key1 libvorbis0a libvorbis0a:i386
  libvorbisenc2 libvorbisenc2:i386 libvorbisfile3 libvorbisfile3:i386 libvte-2.91-0 libvte-2.91-common libwacom-bin libwacom-common libwacom2
  libwagon-file-java libwagon-http-shaded-java libwagon-provider-api-java libwavpack1 libwayland-client0 libwayland-cursor0 libwayland-egl1
  libwayland-server0 libwbclient0 libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwebsocket-api-java libwhoopsie0 libwind0-heimdal libwind0-heimdal:i386 libwine
  libwine:i386 libwinpr2-2 libwmf0.2-7 libwmf0.2-7-gtk libwnck-3-0 libwnck-3-common libwpd-0.10-10 libwpg-0.3-3 libwrap0 libwrap0:i386
  libwww-perl libxapian30 libxatracker2 libxcb-dri2-0 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0 libxcb-glx0:i386
  libxcb-icccm4 libxcb-present0 libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-randr0 libxcb-render0 libxcb-render0:i386 libxcb-res0 libxcb-shape0 libxcb-shm0
  libxcb-shm0:i386 libxcb-sync1 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-xfixes0 libxcb-xkb1 libxcb-xtest0 libxcb-xv0 libxcb1 libxcb1:i386 libxcb1-dev
  libxcursor1 libxcursor1:i386 libxinerama1 libxinerama1:i386 libxklavier16 libxml-libxml-perl libxml-parser-perl libxml-twig-perl libxml2
  libxml2:i386 libxmlsec1 libxmlsec1-nss libxtables12 libyajl2 libyaml-libyaml-perl libyelp0 libzeitgeist-2.0-0 libzmq5 libzstd1
  libzvbi-common libzvbi0 lintian linux-firmware linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic linux-libc-dev linux-signed-generic
  locales login logrotate lsb-base lsb-release lsof ltrace man-db maven media-player-info mesa-va-drivers mesa-vdpau-drivers modemmanager
  mount mousetweaks mtools multiarch-support mutter mutter-common mythes-en-us nano nautilus nautilus-data nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal
  nautilus-sendto ncurses-base ncurses-bin netbase netcat-openbsd netplan.io network-manager network-manager-config-connectivity-ubuntu
  network-manager-gnome network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome network-manager-pptp network-manager-pptp-gnome
  networkd-dispatcher notification-daemon ntfs-3g openjdk-11-jdk openjdk-11-jdk-headless openjdk-11-jre openjdk-11-jre-headless
  openjdk-8-jre-headless openprinting-ppds openssh-client openssl openvpn orca p11-kit p11-kit-modules packagekit packagekit-tools parted
  passwd patch pcmciautils perl perl-base plymouth plymouth-label plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text policykit-1
  policykit-desktop-privileges poppler-utils ppp pptp-linux printer-driver-foo2zjs printer-driver-foo2zjs-common printer-driver-gutenprint
  printer-driver-hpcups printer-driver-min12xxw printer-driver-postscript-hp printer-driver-sag-gdi procps psmisc publicsuffix pulseaudio
  pulseaudio-module-bluetooth pulseaudio-utils python python-all python-all-dev python-apt-common python-cairo python-cffi-backend
  python-crypto python-cryptography python-dbus python-dev python-entrypoints python-gi python-keyring python-keyrings.alt python-minimal
  python-pip python-pip-whl python-pkg-resources python-setuptools python-six python-wheel python-xdg python2 python2-dev python2-minimal
  python2.7 python2.7-dev python2.7-minimal python3 python3-apport python3-apt python3-aptdaemon python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python3-brlapi
  python3-cairo python3-cffi-backend python3-chardet python3-cryptography python3-cups python3-cupshelpers python3-dbus python3-debconf
  python3-debian python3-distro-info python3-distupgrade python3-entrypoints python3-gdbm python3-gi python3-gi-cairo python3-httplib2
  python3-jwt python3-keyring python3-lazr.restfulclient python3-louis python3-macaroonbakery python3-markupsafe python3-minimal python3-nacl
  python3-netifaces python3-oauthlib python3-pil python3-pkg-resources python3-problem-report python3-protobuf python3-pyatspi
  python3-pymacaroons python3-renderpm python3-reportlab python3-reportlab-accel python3-requests python3-simplejson python3-six
  python3-software-properties python3-speechd python3-systemd python3-tz python3-uno python3-update-manager python3-urllib3 python3-xdg
  python3-yaml qpdf readline-common remmina remmina-common remmina-plugin-rdp remmina-plugin-secret remmina-plugin-vnc rfkill rhythmbox
  rhythmbox-data rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar rhythmbox-plugins rsync rsyslog rtkit samba-libs sane-utils seahorse sed
  session-migration shim-signed shotwell shotwell-common simple-scan snapd software-properties-common software-properties-gtk
  speech-dispatcher speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins speech-dispatcher-espeak-ng speedtest-cli spice-vdagent squashfs-tools strace sudo
  switcheroo-control syslinux syslinux-common system-config-printer system-config-printer-common system-config-printer-udev systemd
  systemd-sysv t1utils tar telnet thermald thunderbird thunderbird-gnome-support thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-gb
  thunderbird-locale-en-us totem totem-common totem-plugins transmission-common transmission-gtk tzdata ubuntu-advantage-tools ubuntu-docs
  ubuntu-drivers-common ubuntu-mono ubuntu-release-upgrader-core ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk ubuntu-report ubuntu-session ubuntu-settings
  ubuntu-software ubuntu-wallpapers ubuntu-wallpapers-cosmic ubuntu-web-launchers ucf udev udisks2 ufw unattended-upgrades uno-libs3 unzip
  update-inetd update-manager update-manager-core update-notifier update-notifier-common upower ure usb-creator-common usb-creator-gtk usbmuxd
  usbutils util-linux uuid-runtime va-driver-all vim vim-common vim-runtime vim-tiny vino wget whiptail whoopsie wine wine32:i386 wine64
  winetricks wireless-tools wpasupplicant x11-common xbrlapi xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-gtk xdg-user-dirs xdg-user-dirs-gtk
  xfonts-base xorg xserver-common xserver-xephyr xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all xserver-xorg-input-libinput
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-legacy xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu xserver-xorg-video-ati
  xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-radeon xserver-xorg-video-vesa xwayland xxd xz-utils
  yaru-theme-gnome-shell yaru-theme-gtk yaru-theme-icon yaru-theme-sound yelp yelp-xsl zeitgeist-core zenity zenity-common zlib1g zlib1g:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1496 not upgraded.
```

I tried the options suggested in *[“The following packages have been kept back:” Why and how do I solve it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it)*, *[How can I fix apt error “W: Target Packages … is configured multiple times”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories/192388#192388)*, *[I am trying to upgrade from ubuntu 18.10 to 19.04, and am unable to](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1137923/i-am-trying-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-18-10-to-19-04-and-am-unable-to)*, and few more links.

A similar message (`0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1496 not upgraded.`) is seen when I try using other commands. Is there a way this can be overcome and the upgrade be executed?

Comment: Why do you have `apt-get dist-upgrade` listed as your method of release-upgrading from 18.10 to 19.04?  Ubuntu has different tested & intended tools for release-upgrading to debian, refer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DiscoDingo/ReleaseNotes in the "*Upgrading from Ubuntu 18.10*" section

Comment: Since you seem unable to fix even the minor multiple-configured-sources issue successfully, untangling your terrifying and unwise mix of bionic, cosmic, and disco sources might be beyond your current skills. Consider preserving your data to some other media and then doing a clean-install. In the future, avoid mixing sources and packages from different releases of Ubuntu, lest your system become a mess again.

Comment: @guiverc, I've followed the steps earlier. I get the Update Manager Window with Upgrade button(along with OK and Settings button). However, clicking Upgrade closes the window, but does nothing after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite a bit of effort I was able to fix this issue. Here's what I tried.

1. I updated the sources to a single release, in my case it was to
   Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish).
2. Subsequently I resolved the second part of the issue by marking the held packages as unhold (`sudo apt-mark unhold <package-name>`). Note that multiple names for `package-name` can be separated by spaces, but **not newline characters**.
3. Next I executed the below commands

   ```
       sudo apt-get update
       sudo apt-get upgrade
       sudo do-release-upgrade
   ```

   All the steps ran smoothly and finally I was able to upgrade
   successfully to Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo). Please restart Ubuntu whenever prompted during the above steps.