# The following packages have been kept back - safe to force install?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

On doing `sudo apt upgrade`, I get the following error (or warning, not sure what it is):

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libnvidia-cfg1-440 libnvidia-compute-440 libnvidia-compute-440:i386 libnvidia-decode-440 libnvidia-decode-440:i386 libnvidia-encode-440 libnvidia-encode-440:i386
  libnvidia-extra-440 libnvidia-fbc1-440 libnvidia-fbc1-440:i386 libnvidia-gl-440 libnvidia-gl-440:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-440 libnvidia-ifr1-440:i386
  nvidia-compute-utils-440 nvidia-driver-440 nvidia-kernel-common-440 nvidia-kernel-source-440 nvidia-utils-440 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 20 not upgraded.
```

I found the solution (run `sudo apt install <package-name>`). I also found out why it does so. It is because the newer version has unmet dependencies.

But my doubt is, is it safe to do `sudo apt install <package-name>`, or will the system take care of it in a few days. If so, then how many days would it take to resolve this on its own?

**EDIT 1:**
My current Nvidia Drivers are 440.

Comment: It depends upon the missing dependencies. Simply running `sudo apt install <package-name>` should fail due to the same missing dependencies. We recommend against forcing package installs without a better reason.

Comment: Does anything come up for suggested removal when you use `sudo apt autoremove`?  Which version of the NVIDIA driver are you using?

Comment: @Nmath no nothing comes for autoremove, and I am using 440 nvidia drivers.

Comment: @user535733 hence I did not do it, cause I didn't want to force anything, as it might break some working things.

Comment: @PabloBianchi my question is not how to solve it. Read my question again.

Comment: Please consider reading the answers presented [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it), I believe you'll find the answer to your question. Also consider improving your manners.

Comment: @PabloBianchi I am sorry if that sounded rude. It was not intended to be rude at all. And yes, I have read the answers on that post, but I did not get the answer to the question - is it safe to force upgrade using the solutions given in that post. No where in those answers did people claim that it was safe (except dist-upgrade which they said was unsafe). And neither did people say that it will be automatically resolved and in what time frame. Once again sorry if my previous comment sounded rude.

Comment: @Nmath I solved it by using the `software upgrader` in ubuntu. What could be the reason that worked and not the terminal commands? Or was it because I was using the Nouveau drivers. Before the update from the `software upgrader`, under additional drivers Noveau was selected and now 450 proprietary is selected.

Comment: I'm not sure -- it's much more difficult to troubleshoot a problem that's already been solved.  In any case, if you have a solution, you should definitely post the answer below so that your contribution is helpful for future visitors.

Comment: I had the same problem with version 440 (but only 2 files kept back). (I use ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa repository). Solved it by doing a search on "nvidia" in synaptic manager. It showed 2 broken packages. Marked them for removal (and I also marked the nouveau driver for removal). Applied. Then in terminal did : "sudo ubuntu-drivers devices && sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall"     
-> Version 455 installed without problem

Comment: For me selecting a newer version of NVIDIA driver from 470 to 495 under the Additional Drivers tab in the Software & Updates thingy worked.

Answer (score 18):

There are normally four reasons why you may see this message:

- **The upgrade procedure needs to *add* packages**: [Use `--with-new-pkgs upgrade`](https://askubuntu.com/a/862799/349837). Without this, `apt upgrade` won't add or remove new packages.
- **The upgrade procedure needs to *remove* packages**: Double-check your apt configuration, which packages will be removed, analyze the possible consequences, check your backups… and only then: `apt full-upgrade`. Will add **or remove** packages as necessary to complete the upgrade.

  > `apt full-upgrade` is only dangerous if you have bad repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list*`. It's good to be aware that `full-upgrade` upgrades all packages, but with the default repositories, that should be fine. *Not* using `full-upgrade` could be dangerous, as you might miss security updates.<sup>[source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it#comment288788_18694)</sup>

  > `apt full-upgrade` can remove as well as add packages, but it is not really dangerous. Any package installation command can cause serious damage if you have problems in your sources.list file! A regular `apt upgrade` command will install any package from any software source that is enabled; `full-upgrade` is not unique in this way.<sup>[source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it#comment340180_18694)</sup>
- **Relevant packages are marked as held back**: `sudo apt-mark showmanual | grep nvidia` (for e.g.), one of the listed packages are the trouble ones listed by `apt upgrade`? In this case should be analyzed who/why these packages were marked like that.

  For example, I had [an issue](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/5434) with `flatpak`, fixed by moving from 1.11.1 to 1.14.4 by adding its PPA. For some reason, flatpak mark as held back `xdg-desktop-portal` (*desktop integration portal for Flatpak and Snap*).
- **It depends on packages or versions that are not available**: This might be a temporary issue or an apt misconfiguration.

  - This temporary case could sometimes be related to [Phased Updates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates#Phasing) (also [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PhasedUpdates)):

    > Once an update is released to -updates, the update is then phased so that the update is gradually made available to expanding subsets of Ubuntu users. This process allows us to automatically monitor for regressions and halt the update process if any are found.
    >
    > The Phased-Update-Percentage is initially set to 10%, and a job is run (every 6 hours) that checks for regressions and if none are found the phased update percentage will be incremented by 10%. So an update will become fully phased after 54 hours or about 2 days.
    >
    > Update Manager is currently *the only package manager that supports phased updates*. Any other update mechanism installs all updates regardless of the Phased-Update-Percentage.

### Other notes

- Unsure about using `full-upgrade`? Try it with `--dry-run`. From [apt manual](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man8/apt-get.8.html#options):

  > `-s`, `--simulate`, `--just-print`, `--dry-run`, `--recon`, `--no-act`:
  > No action; perform a simulation of events that would occur based on the current system state but do not actually change the system.
- `dist-upgrade` will not update the whole distribution (like `do-release-upgrade`). It is a misnomer. [`full-upgrade` is equivalent](https://askubuntu.com/a/770140/349837). Avoid using `dist-upgrade`.
- Use [`apt` command](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt.8.en.html), the [friendly alternative](https://itsfoss.com/apt-vs-apt-get-difference/) to [`apt-get`](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt-get.8.en.html).

---

Sometimes `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` might try to downgrade your NVIDIA drivers. I'm not sure why.

Comment: apt full-upgrade didn't help me, but the following did: sudo apt-get install aptitude 
sudo aptitude safe-upgrade

Comment: Yeah, I still get `The following packages have been kept back` when I do `sudo apt-get full-upgrade`.  Seems to me the bottom line is that this is a UX bug, in that apt/apt-get gives no indication about _why_ the packages are held back.  I'll try to find or, if necessary, report a bug in the appropriate place (which I'll need to find...)

Comment: @lindes I'm pretty sure your case is not a bug. Which packages? Are listed with `sudo apt-mark showmanual`? Do you have a default `sources.list`?

Comment: @PabloBianchi - it's a _user experience_ bug, in that it says things have been kept back, but gives no indication as to why, so causes confusion. The reason is because of "Phased Updates" (see e.g. https://askubuntu.com/q/601/222533 and the comments there, which link to further questions), but there's no indication of such in the user interface. Hence, we have questions like this one on askubuntu... because it's confusing.  It wouldn't be so confusing if it said "have been kept back due to phased updates" (with or without "(see _<url>_ for more information on phased updates)" as well) instead.